# Apple ID change

Tags: iphone

I changed my Apple ID to my new email address.  Now when I receive a text message, the box showing my old Apple ID and request for password appears.  Is there a way to make this stop happening?

Answer (score 1):

When the old password prompt is incorrect, you may need to sign out of the services using Apple ID one by one.

- Messages
- FaceTime
- App and iTunes stores
- Find My Phone / Find My Friends
- iCloud (do this last and only of needed)

Once the device signs out, your secure token and device ID should clear instantly, but consider waiting 15 minutes before signing back in. Use that time to sign in to http://appleid.apple.com to clear out any old addresses, credit cards, rescue emails, etc...

Also, I would sign out of any other computers or iOS devices that used that email on Messages.

Once I needed to contact Apple support to clear a account, but you could also just leave it signed out overnight and try after a longer stetch than 15 minutes as well.